# mousewheel event is not working in ie

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application and I need to track the mouse wheel movement but my functions are not working as I expect in Internet Explorer. It works in all other browsers but not IE, any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

JS...

```
var request = true;
var onMouseWheelSpin = function(event) {
    if(request === true){ 
        request = false;
        var nDelta = 0;
        if (!event) { event = window.event; }
        // cross-bowser handling of eventdata to boil-down delta (+1 or -1)
        if ( event.wheelDelta ) { // IE and Opera
            nDelta= event.wheelDelta;
            if ( window.opera ) {  // Opera has the values reversed
                nDelta= -nDelta;
            }
        }
        else if (event.detail) { // Mozilla FireFox
            nDelta= -event.detail;
        }
        if (nDelta > 0) {
            zoomFun( 1, event );
        }
        if (nDelta < 0) {
            zoomFun( -1, event );
        }
        if ( event.preventDefault ) {  // Mozilla FireFox
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        event.returnValue = false;  // cancel default action
    }
}

var zoomFun = function(delta,e) {
    if(delta > 0){ // zoom in
        alert("In");
    }else{ // zoom out
        alert("Out");
    }
    request = true;
}

var setupMouseWheel = function(){
    // for mouse scrolling in Firefox
    var elem = document.getElementById("zoom");
    if (elem.addEventListener) {    // all browsers except IE before version 9
        // Internet Explorer, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari
        elem.addEventListener ("mousewheel", onMouseWheelSpin, false);
        // Firefox
        elem.addEventListener ("DOMMouseScroll", onMouseWheelSpin, false);
    }else{
        if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE before version 9
            elem.attachEvent ("onmousewheel", onMouseWheelSpin);
        }
    }   
}
```

I am calling the setupMouseWheel function onload in the body aka

```
<body onload="setupMouseWheel();">
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a great cross browser approach here for anyone who has a similar issue

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/wheel

Comment: but no IE8 support? :-(

Answer (score 15):

To listen to the mouse wheel, it's best to listen to `DOMMouseScroll`, `mousewheel` and `wheel`. The last one is IE, and is the only one you're not listening for.

I'll also point out that jQuery has a shortcut for binding multiple events:

```
 $(elem).on("DOMMouseScroll mousewheel wheel", onMouseWheelSpin);
```

update: noticed that though you tagged this as jQuery, you're not actually using it. To do this without jQuery, just carry on as you are but add a `wheel` event listener like the others.

Comment: oh and since you're using jQuery, you should use `$(document).ready(function(){blah});` instead of the body's `onload`. It's less likely to interfere with other code on the page.

Comment: I tagged jquery so that I could expand to those who may have other solutions, but I try to use javascript when it doesn't add too much to the code. thanks for the info, ill try it now

Comment: Your approach js and jquery did not actually fix the issue in IE, but I did find a really great cross browser approach on the mozilla site thanks for answering +1